# Git should include Folder/Files only for master branch

Tags: git, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment, gitignore, branching-and-merging

I have a public folder with minified files for deployment. But this folder is only important for deployment on master branch. The other branches used this folder with plain generated files and we can work with .gitignore.

How can I include a folder only for master branch? We dont like to change the .gitignore on master branch every time.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branch-permissions-776639807.html

Comment: Why you don't use the same folder for deployment and production? otherwise create a subfolder for your environment.

Answer (score 1):

The minimized files which you actually put into deployment, while appearing to be source files, are actually artifacts of the build process.  It is unlikely that you would/should be changing these minimized files.

As a general rule, files which arise from the build process should not be versioned by Git ane I feel this is the case with your minimized files.  So personally I would not even version the minimized folder.  Rather, just version the regular source files, and let your deployment process minimize and deploy the appropriate things.

Comment: Yes, I´m with you.. But the problem is the deployment.. we used Microsoft Azure with git deployment.. the master Branch goes in production and needs all relevant files... On other branches we would like to  ignore the public folder..

See as example: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-deploy-local-git/

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure, but does it let you run your own build scripts in the cloud?  My guess is that it does, in which case you would only need to include a script for minifying the source files.

Comment: You shouldn't be forced to use bad/weird practice because of a build tool.

Comment: We build local with Gulp and Webpack (Angular CLI).. The git deployment is very good.. but we only have a problem with the public folder and git.. that kills a productive development workflow..

Comment: I'm out of things to say, but I would just suggest to find a way to include the minimized files only after the build.  Maybe @VonC can help you further.